# Is "as a sign of their mutual consent" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is "as a sign of their mutual consent" idiomatic?

> As a sign of their mutual consent, the two scientists exchanged their ink pens.

or should it be re-phrased somehow?

**EDIT:**

**My concern:**

1) I am not sure if it's okay to say "a sign of mutual consent". I know that it's okay to say "a sign of consent" and I also know that it's okay to say "mutual consent", but I am not sure if "as a sign of mutual consent" is okay;

2) I am not sure if the structure "as a [one thing], [another thing]..." is okay in English. For example, in my first language, the grammar prohibits such sentences like:

> "As a sign of their agreement, they exchanged their pens"
>
> "As a native speaker, this collocation doesn't sound idiomatic to me"

allowing only such sentences like:

> "As a sign of their agreement, their exchange of pens was especially
>   meaningful."
>
> "As a native speaker, I don't find this collocation idiomatic"

**Context:**

Two scientists agreeing with each other on which direction of their research to take, the research having already been in a non-progress state for quite a while due to their disagreements.

**Intended meaning:**

Reporting a symbolic gesture performed by two scientists that marks the end of the time of their disagreements.

Comment: This doe not answer your question, but do you really mean to use _consent_? If the scientists agree on some theory, or or some research plan, _agreement_ is a better word to use. If they consent to being used as research subjects by each other, _consent_ would fit. If they were to enter in a (sexual)_ relationship, _mutual consent_ would certainly fit as well, but the pens would be surprising...

Comment: @oerkelens - So, "to consent" seems to be quite different in meaning from "to agree". Does it always have a sexual connotation? What about two people agreeing to marry each other? Would "consent" in this case  be more suitable than agreeing? From some examples in dictionaries I can tell that sexual connotation may still not be there (like in "Can my child be medically examined without my consent?"), but it looks like the giver of concent agrees to be used as an object of some activity. Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: Consent is used to denote specific _forms_ of agreement, indeed. And there is not _a;ways_ a sexual connotation, but _age of consent_ is about sex, and _mutual consent_ is usually used in a sexual context. In case of marriage, it sounds weird to my (Western) ear.

Comment: @oerkelens - "In case of marriage, it sounds weird to my (Western) ear" - So what would you say then instead of, say, "As a sign of their consent to marry each other, the two lovers have exchanged their betrothal rings"?

Comment: In that sentence, I would expect _intent_. Using _consent_ would make it sound as if they "give in" to external pressure, like in an arranged marriage. Traditionally, _consent_ to a marriage was given _by_ a third party (e.g. parents), especially when the marriage candidates were under age.

Comment: @oerkelens - I see. Thank you. Just one more additional question: Would you also expect the word _intent_ if it were not betrothal, but marriage rings exchanged at the wedding ceremony?

Comment: _Wedding_ rings (not marriage rings) are a symbol of devotion to the marriage, not of an intent to marry someone, but if anything, an intent to fulfil the obligations of that marriage.

Comment: @oerkelens - So, would it be okay then to say (about the wedding rings) "as a sign of their mutual devotion" ?

Comment: @oerkelens - Wedding rings are different from marriage rings???

Comment: Yes, "mutual devotion" is ok. And there are no "marriage rings". Weddings rings are exchanged at a wedding, which is the ceremony that starts a _marriage_. Maybe you should consider asking separate questions, because the comments section is not for these kind of exchanges :)

Comment: @oerkelens - Ah, okay I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct and understandable, but exchanging pens is a slightly odd way to show **mutual consent**  Often some document is signed.